# How can I authenticate websocket over HTTP connection?

Tags: authentication, http, websocket

I have to communicate over HTTP connection only.

A WebSocket server is setup in Tomcat. A web application is also running on the server.

Now, I have a scenario in which a client will login into the web application using browser. Upon successful login a WebSocket connection will be created.

Same way mobile application will use this web application for API calls and after successful login a WebSocket connection will be created from mobile application also.

Now, I want to restrict the WebSocket connection to be created only from either this mobile application or from browser after logging in.

How can I prevent connection comming from any source other than my application?

I read about JSON Web Token and OAuth 2 and found OAuth 2 very complex and also that it makes more sense to use if a third-party application need to use some data. On the other hand JWT looks like what I am searching for but, as the request header contains the token and HTTP connection uses plain-text, the token can be very easily stolen.

So, how can I authenticate a WebSocket over HTTP?

Comment: During the WebSocket connection setup, the HTTP cookies are sent inside of the handshake.  If there is any sort of session identifier there, the server has access to it. After the handshake, your client and server scripts will need to coordinate session tokens, i.e., through AJAX requests running parallel to the WS connection.  The best _on-topic_ answer here is: **Use a session token**. As for _how_ to use that token, that's a question best answered on StackOverflow, since it involves writing code.

Comment: There are [several similar questions at this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+authenticate+websocket). Please check these first and if necessary ask the details which are not already answered. Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to authenticate an user using a websocket?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73076/whats-the-best-way-to-authenticate-an-user-using-a-websocket)